# Scrolling in FlatList Element React Native

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I am making a todo app, to render the list of todo items i am using flatlist but in flatlist i am not able to scroll through the list is there any way to sroll throught the list

my code

`

```
      <FlatList 
        data={toDos}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={() => {
          loadToDoList();
          setIsRefreshing(true);
        }}
        renderItem={renderToDoItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
```

`

i tried using scroll view but i dont know how to use it can you please help me fix this problem

Comment: The shared code is not sufficient to solve your problem. Share the whole component including styles.

Answer (score 0):

code

```js
  let showToDoList = () => {
    return (
      <FlatList 
        data={toDos}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={() => {
          loadToDoList();
          setIsRefreshing(true);
        }}
        renderItem={renderToDoItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}/>
    );
  };
```

todo item

```js
  let renderToDoItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={[MyStyles.ToDoItem]}>
        <View style={AppStyles.fillSpace}>
          <BouncyCheckbox
            isChecked={item.completed}
            size={25}
            fillColor="#0A7AFF"
            unfillColor="#fff"
            text={item.text}
            iconStyle={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
            onPress={(isChecked) => {
              checkToDoItem(item, isChecked);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <CustomTextButton
          text={<AntDesign name="delete" size={25} color="red" />}
          onPress={() => deleteToDo(item.id)}
          style={MyStyles.ToDoDelete}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

styles

```js
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default StyleSheet.create({
  ToDoItem: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 3,
    marginBottom: 3,
    marginLeft: 7,
    marginRight: 7,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderColor: "#D9D9D9",
  },
  CustomButtonAddToDo: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: 100,
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#ff7676",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  Center: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  CustomTextButton: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#87F1FF",
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  FloatingContainer: {
    width: 77,
    height: 77,
    backgroundColor: "#46A16E",
    borderRadius: 100,
    display: "flex",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  Floating: {},
  blackText: {
    color: "#000",
  },
  whiteText: {
    color: "#fff",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 30,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  MainBG: {
    backgroundColor: "#798478",
  },
  TopBar: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  TopBarText: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  TopBarTextMenu: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  TopBarMenu: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  addToDoText: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  menuicon: {
    width: 35,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    margin: 50,
  },
  lightText: {
    color: "#fff"
  }, 
  lightTextInput: {
    color: "#fff"
  },
  darkText: {
    color: "#000"
  }, 
  darkTextInput: {
    color: "#000"
  },
  bold: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  smallText: {
    color: "5a5a59",
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "300",
  },
});
```

styles2

```js
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 16,
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  topMargin: {
    marginTop: 16,
  },
  bottomMargin: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  rightMargin: {
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  leftMargin: {
    marginLeft: 16,
  },
  lightText: {
    color: "white",
  },
  
  darkText: {
    color: "black",
  },
  errorText: {
    color: "#FF0000",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  textInput: {
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    padding: 8,
  },
  lightTextInput: {
    borderBottomColor: "white",
  },
  InlineTextButton: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#87F1FF",
  },
  pressedInlineTextButton: {
    fontSize: 19,
    color: "#87F1FF",
    opacity: 0.4,
  },
  
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 16
  },
  noPadding: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    marginVertical: 4,
  },
  fillSpace: {
    flex: 1
  },
  rightAligned: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  leftAligned: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  topMargin: {
    marginTop: 16
  },
  bottomMargin: {
    marginBottom: 16
  },
  rightMargin: {
    marginRight: 16
  },
  leftMargin: {
    marginLeft: 16
  },
  backgroundCover: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  lightText: {
    color: "#fff"
  },
  errorText: {
    color: "#ff0000"
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: "center"
  },
  textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    padding: 8,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    marginVertical: 8
  },
  lightTextInput: {
    borderBottomColor: "#ffffff"
  },
  darkTextInput: {
    borderBottomColor: "#000000"
  },
  InlineTextButton: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#87F1FF",
  },
  pressedInlineTextButton: {
    fontSize: 19,
    color: "#87F1FF",
    opacity: 0.4,
  },
});
```